# module "QtQuick.XmlListModel" is not installed?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

I use PyQt6 and try run some qml app,It throw out `module "QtQuick.XmlListModel" is not installed`  errors ?

```
Name: PyQt6
Version: 6.2.0
Summary: Python bindings for the Qt cross platform application toolkit
Home-page: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/
Author: Riverbank Computing Limited
Author-email: info@riverbankcomputing.com
License: GPL v3
Location: c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: PyQt6-Qt6, PyQt6-sip
Required-by:
```

**Code Snippet**

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt6, XmlListModel was moved from QtQuick to QtQml as indicated in [the docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.2/qml-qtqml-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html) so you must change to:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQml.XmlListModel
```

Note: In Qt6 you should not indicate the versions of the modules.

Comment: 14:54:22: Starting C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -u E:\qttest\07-modelview\main.py...
file:///E:/qttest/07-modelview/main.qml:2:1: Cannot load library C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyQt6\Qt6\qml\QtQml\XmlListModel\qmlxmllistmodelplugin.dll: ????????????顣 , It run with errors?

Comment: @jie You seem to have not installed the package correctly, did you select the option to add python to the PATH environment variable when you installed it?

Comment: Yes,I had. `PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\.dotnet\tools`